# Adding data objects integers to localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to add data objects returned from the server and store them in local storage.

`data.Total` is a set of integer numbers that come from the server on successful requests.
I somehow need to add them before storing them in local storage

```
let score = data.Total+localStorage.getItem("RelationScore");
let removeNull = score.replace('null', '');
localStorage.setItem("RelationScore", removeNull );
```

Example Output: `1234`

I want to add those and store them to a single variable, so the result based on the example should be `10`

Comment: Is this an "example output" of data.Total?

Comment: correct, they are integers but i need to add these

Comment: @GragasIncoming Is the data being returned on success as an array of integers, one integer value of 1234 or 1,234, a json string???

Comment: it returns a single number on each request for example `1`

Comment: @GragasIncoming So you are making multiple requests and returning one individual integer number on each request and you need to get the sum of all the requests?

Comment: yeah exactly. And store the result on local storage. Then update it on each request

Comment: @GragasIncoming I see what you are doing, but I question this design. Why would you need to query the backend over and over for something that could be returned as one value, the sum of all parts?

Comment: Because there is some server side validation that returns specific numbers depending on the validation, that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All items are saved into `localStorage` as string, So you will need to parse them first:

```
let score = localStorage.getItem("RelationScore");
score = score === null ? 0 : parseInt(score);
localStorage.setItem("RelationScore", data.Total + score);
```

I assume that `data.Total` is an integer like you said. If it is not, then you'll have to parse it too.

If you want to only update the total when the item is not zero:

```
let score = localStorage.getItem("RelationScore");
if(score !== null) {
    score = parseInt(score);
    if(score !==0)
        localStorage.setItem("RelationScore", data.Total + score);
}
```

Comment: If you stop editing i will give it a shot :) Also i don't care if the number is 0.

Comment: Basically you want to get the item from the `localStorage` once, then you check if it is `null` or not. This is better than the other answers which get the item twice unnecessarily. If the item is 0, then adding it to the total will have no effect. OK, for efficiency if you want to only update when the item is not zero or null, you can add a check. I will update my answer.

Comment: Note that the result could also be a float number

Comment: The title and description of your question said integer numbers, so update your question to correct that. Simply use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you're probably looking for this code :

```
let stored = (localStorage.getItem("RelationScore") === null ? 0 : parseInt(localStorage.getItem("RelationScore")));
let score = parseInt(data.Total) + stored;
localStorage.setItem("RelationScore", score);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you put an Integer into localStorage, it's going to be saved as a String.

If you add a number to a String in JavaScript, you are just appending the number to the String,  `"10" + 1234 === "101234";`. So you will need to parse the String to a number:

```
let score = 0;

if (localStorage.getItem("RelationScore")) { // if the Item exists 
  score += parseInt(localStorage.getItem("RelationScore")); // make a number out of it and add it to the score
}

score += parseInt(data.Total); // add data.Total, even if the Item hasn't already been set

localStorage.setItem("RelationScore", score); // finally save the score to localStorage
```